# Why doesn't this code open the "site.txt" file from the popup menu of system tray icon?

Tags: java, windows, awt, actionlistener, desktop

```
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        File sitetxt = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "site.txt");
        MenuItem settings = new MenuItem("Settings");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    desktop.open(sitetxt);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println("site.txt not found.");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        popup.add(settings);

        trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);
```

I'm trying to open a text file when the user clicks "Settings" from the right click menu of the system tray icon. The default text editor is set to Notepad. There is another menu item called "Exit" but it works fine.

Comment: You wrote `exit.addActionListener`.  Did you mean to write `settings.addActionListener`?

Comment: @VGR Yeah that was stupid. Should remember to use refrator next time. Thank you.